# Is it possible in nginx while setting up reverse proxy to have server parameter as variable based on browser cookie in upstream module?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am setting up nginx reverse proxy for routing/load distribution using upstream and server modules where same URL should proxy to 5 different servers running Apache, without changing the URL in the browser, depending on the value of the cookie.  How do I accomplish server parameter in upstream to pass a variable based on cookie value?

I have tried mapping cookie value to server that I need to proxy to and then have used the server ip as a variable in "server_name" parameter.  I am trying to use the same in "server" parameter in upstream, however nginx does not support that.  I do not want to put all 5 servers in upstream as then nginx is trying to load balance across them, that is not the goal here.  The goal is to distribute load to specific servers based on cookie value.

nginx.conf file

```
http {
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

upstream su.la.com {
  server 100.0.8.2:443; 
}
}

    #The above works, making this $suhost, does not work.Any alternative 
    for this will be helpful.

    suhosts.conf file under /etc/nginx/conf.d

map $cookie_su_ID $suhost {
    default 100.0.8.2;
    1     100.0.8.2;
    3     100.0.8.6;
}

server {

  set $bypass 0;
  if ($remote_addr ~ "^(127.0.0.1)$") {
    set $bypass $http_secret_header;
  }

  listen 80;
  server_name su.la.com;

  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

  server {

  set $bypass 0;
  if ($remote_addr ~ "^(127.0.0.1)$") {
    set $bypass $http_secret_header;
  }

  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name $suhost;
      ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/client.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/client.private.key;

    location / {
            proxy_pass https://su.la.com;
            proxy_cache_bypass $bypass;
      }
 }
```

Expected results:
Based on map function described above, if su_id=1, the server parameter in upstream $suhost, should be picked up as 100.0.8.2 and https://su.la.com should route to 100.0.8.2, with no change in browser.

Actual Results:
nginx does not allow variable for server parameter, so need other alternatives or approach to make this happen.  If server parameter is given a value for a single server, this works.  We need to make it work for routing to multiple servers, single server at a time, based on cookie value.

Comment: Anyone who has run into this or can help?